# How to access the internal id of neo4j node?

Tags: neo4j

I know I should avoid using the internal id in neo4j but is there a way to access the internal id of a node in neo4j and RETURN DISTINCT all the nodes based on this internal id?

I have tried this:

```
         match (n) where id(n)=123 return n;
```

This return me the node with internal id=123 but how can I get all the nodes exist in database based on the internal id?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Imagine the following:

```
CREATE (:SomeLabel {myId:123})-[:someRelationshipType]->(:SomeLabel {myId:456})
```

This will create a two nodes with a relationship between them. The relationship is of type `someRelationshipType`.

So, what happens if you execute the following query?

```
MATCH 
    (s:SomeLabel)-[rel:someRelationshipType]->(target:SomeLabel)
RETURN 
    ID(s),       // Built-in Neo4j function to retrieve the internal node id
    s.myId,      // Access the property myId that you created above
    LABELS(s),   // Lists all labels for the start node
    ID(rel),     // Built-in Neo4j function to retrieve the internal relationship id
    TYPE(rel),   // Built-in Neo4j function to retrieve the relationship type
    ID(target),  // Built-in Neo4j function to retrieve the internal node id
    target.myId  // Access the property myId that you created above
```

The output of the query is something like:

```
ID(root) | root.myId | LABELS(root) | ID(rel) | TYPE(rel)            | ID(target) | target.myId
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
192      | 123       | SomeLabel    | 271     | someRelationshipType | 193        | 456
```

This shows a few interesting things. First, there are a couple of built-in functions that return values that you have not provided yourself. The `ID()` function returns the **internal ID of the node or relationship**. This is a generated id that you can not control yourself, it is totally handled by the database (and it may even be reused so you can't really rely on those values). Each node has got **exactly one internal id** and it is unique throughout the entire database, hence you can never find multiple nodes with the same internal id.

But, in the query above there is also a property called `myId`. There can be multiple nodes that actually has the same value for that property since it is a property that we created ourselves. The only way to make sure that those properties contains unique values isis to use the `UNIQUE`-constraint ([see the docs here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-constraints.html)).

Unique constraints can be set using this syntax:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:SomeLabel) ASSERT n.myId IS UNIQUE
```

The other functions that are part of the original `MATCH`-query are:

- `LABELS` - returns a list of all [labels](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/graphdb-neo4j-labels.html) that are part of the node
- `TYPE` - returns the relationship type that was specified when creating the node.

A final note, if you want to get hold of **all the nodes in the graph** you can use the following query:

```
MATCH (n) RETURN n;
```

But, beware - it is most likely a painful/expensive operation to retrieve all nodes if the graph is big.

Comment: @dkar, no problems - glad if I could help!

Answer (score 1):

There can only be one node at a time with a given internal ID. After you delete a node, its internal ID can be reassigned to a new node, but not before then.

So, your query can only return at most one result.

Comment: Ok. But what I want is to make a:  RETURN DISTINCT (n.internalID). I need this to use it for my data as they don't have any other property which is different.

Comment: I don't understand. The internal ID is assigned by the DB, and the only way to get it from a node is via the ID() function. You can always add your own `id` property to a node, of course, but that is not the same as the "internal ID" -- there is no way for you to explicitly set the internal ID. If this does not make things clear, please provide more information about what your situation.

Comment: Perhaps the confusion is that OP needs to understand that the internal ID in the database **is not a node property**.   So you cannot say `n.internalID` or anything similar.  Instead, to get it you use the `ID()` function.